# UPDATE large number of columns in SQL

Tags: sql, c, sql-update, odbc

In a  database on the cloud, I have a table with about ten thousand columns. I'm going to update it every few minutes with some local data which is the output of a local code (below my_col_val[]). My questions are:

1- What is the best and fastest way to update each row? (For Loop?)

2- Using a char pointer to save the SQL query (szSQL[]) is the best way when it contains a SQL quesry of size of order 1MB?

My code (in C) now roughly looks like:

```
char * szSQL[?];// (What is the best size?)
char * my_col [?];
char * my_col_val[?]; 
SQLHSTMT    hStmt = NULL;

sprintf(szSQL, "UPDATE my_table SET %s='%s',...,%s='%s'\ // there should be 8000 %s='%s' statements
 WHERE ID = my_ID FROM my_table", my_col[0], my_col_val[0], ..., my_col[n], my_col_val[n]); //wher n=8000
SQLExecDirect(hstm, szSQL, SQL_NTS);
```

Comment: Don't you mean ten thousands of rows?

Comment: are you talking about ten thousand columns? :O

Comment: At "about ten thousand columns" ??? Very, very, serious design problem.

Comment: @jarlh
 NO! There are 10000 Columns each contains a data from some sensor.

Comment: A table with ~10K *columns*? If this is not a typo, someone needs to read up on normalization! Also, asking for the "fastest" way on SQL updates. You're asking us to benchmark something for you?...

Comment: @Homer A table with 10K columns is unperformant by default because thats not how you design a table o_O

Comment: @BobRun You mean my design have problem or I should design it with a lot of care?

Comment: @Homer Any design where a table gets 10k columns is poor table design.

Comment: May I suggest 1 record per sensor ?

Comment: That gives you 10k rows , that's probably what you wanted to say ?

Comment: You would be far better off desiging your table in a format similar to "row_id, sensor_id, value"

Comment: @Magisch In my case, each table will represent a machine which contains about 10000 measurements (for sure with different data types). I want to have a table where each row is a snapshot of the measurement at regular time intervals.

Comment: @BobRun please read my reply to Magisch above

Comment: @Homer You should probably come up with another way to store that data then, because 10k columns is ridiculous.

Comment: @Magisch Thank you for your suggestion! I'll consider it!

Comment: @Homer Maybe a column for every data type and another to determine what kind of entry it is? And then just a row for every entry?

Comment: Interesting problem, time series, are you building a local prototype ? I think I would before compounding problems with a cloud db.

Comment: @Magisch Sorry; but I didn' understand your suggestion!

Comment: @Homer Lets say you have 3 different data types and 10.000 different sensors. Make a column "sensor" indicating which sensor it is. Make a column for each data type and for every read of every sensor then generate an entry.

Comment: @BobRun It is a cloud prototype for reading the data from local servers and moving them to a cloud db!

Comment: Lets rephrase the problem, a database where the main table "machine" has the id of each machine, then a table for each machine where we add when the measurement was made and the measurement itself. Is that it ?

Comment: @Magisch Thank you for you interesting suggestion, but there is another requirement: Time. It should be a timeseries solution as well.

Comment: @ BobRun Almost true! But I wouldsay so: There could be more than 100 machines each contains a server with around 10000 measurements. At the moment I'm creating for each server (machine) one table which should record the measurement every 5 minutes.

Comment: You will probably fail to execute a sql statement that tries to update / insert 10'000 columns. Most databases limit the length of a sql statement.

Answer (score 2):

I like @Takarii 's solution using three tables. The best strategy involves 1) how to insert the new rows of measurements and 2) what will it be used for. The latter is of particular interest as that may need additional indexes, and these must be maintained by the db when executing the insert statements. The least indexes are required, the faster the inserts will be. For example, although there is a relation between the three tables, the measurement table could not declare its foreign key with other tables, reducing this index' overhead.

As the table will grow and grow, the db will get slower and slower. Then, it can be beneficial to create a new table for each day of measurements.

As the sensor data is of diferent types, the data could be inserted as string data and only be parsed by the retriever program.

Another help could be that, if the recorded data is only retrieved periodically, the measurements could be written to a flat file and inserted in batch periodically, let's say every hour.

Maybe these ideas can be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, and your request above, Here are my suggestions:

1) As you suggested, an individual table for each machine (not ideal, but will work)

Working on that assumption, you will want an individual row for each sensor, but the problem comes when you need to add additional machines - generally table create privileges are restricted by sysadmins

2) Multiple tables to identify sensor information and assignment, along with a unified results table.

Table 1 - Machine

Table 2 - Sensor

Table 3 - Results

Table 1 would contain the information about the machine with which your sensors are assigned `(machine_id, **insert extra columns as needed**)`

Table 2 contains the sensor information - this is where your potential 10,000 columns would go, however they are now rows with ID's `(sensor_id, sensor_name)`

Table 3 contains the results of the sensor readings, with an assignment to a sensor and then to a machine `(result_id, machine_id(fk), sensor_id(fk), result)`

Then using joins, you can pull out the data for each machine as needed. This will be far more efficient than your current 10k column design

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer but what about the time? I should record the time in the table as well every 5 minutes!

Comment: Thats fine, just add a column in the results table that logs the date/time the result was added.

Comment: Then I need for each time measurement, one column and every 24 hours I will have 288 new columns or 288 copies of Table_3!

Comment: i dont understand why you would have additional copies of the table. All the results get stored there, for each machine. you would simply have additional rows added to the results table

Comment: Ok! I understood what you meant! your suggestion is better as it reduces the #columns but increase the #row!

Comment: Exactly. There is nothing wrong with having large amounts of rows, but having thousands of columns can be a massive restriction on performance. inserts take less time to process than updates too, so you will experience performance boosts based on that too.